# Flask unable to redirect https to https

Tags: python, flask, oauth-2.0

My Flask app is running behind Nginx with a valid SSL certificate from letsencrypt.  I am unable to redirect my web-page to Google's OAuth URL. The browser displays 500 internal server error.  If I copy and paste the OAuth URL in the browser manually, it gets the Google auth page without any issue.

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
        google = OAuth2Session(client_id, scope=scope, redirect_uri=redirect_uri)
        authorization_url,state = google.authorization_url(authorization_base_url,access_type="offline", approval_prompt="force")
        session['oauth_state'] = state
        logger.info("auth url :{au}, state : {s} ".format(au=authorization_url,s=state))
        return redirect(url_for(authorization_url))
```

Comment: Consider using flask-oauthlib, [here's](https://github.com/lepture/flask-oauthlib/blob/master/example/google.py) and example of how create a google client. It works for me behind NGINX and SSL just fine. If you still have an issue, post again.

Comment: i copied the code from the reference page you mentioned and changed the required google codes, but still getting "Internal Server Error", But after little search i used code given [here](https://pythonspot.com/en/login-to-flask-app-with-google/) and it worked....But i'm still want to know what my code above lacks or am i missing anything. thanks @GG_Python